# Let A be an $n\times n$ matrix with complex entries which is not a diagonal matrix. Pick out the cases when A is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be an $n\times n$ matrix with complex entries which is not a diagonal
matrix. Pick out the cases when A is diagonalizable.
*(a)* A is idempotent.
*(b)*  A is nilpotent.
*(c)* A is unitary.

I think *(c)* is true. and *(b)* is false .not sure about *(a)*, though order $2$ idempotent matrices are diagonalizable since it has two distinct eigenvalues $0,1$.but what is the general case .

Comment: i think c is true. and b is false.not sure about a.though order 2 idempotent matrices are diagonalizable since it has two distinct eigenvalues 0,1.but what is the general case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**(a)** : $A$ is idempotent hence $A=A^{2}$ i.e. $A^{2}-A=0$ hence $x^{2}-x=x(x-1)$
is a polynomial $P$ s.t $P(A)=0$. Since the minimal polynomial of
$A$ divides the polynomial we conclude that it is one of the following
$x,x-1,x(x-1)$ . 
In all cases $A$ is diagonalize since the minimal polynomial splits
into a product of coprime linear factors.

**(b)** : $A$ is nilpotent does not guarantee $A$ is diagonalize, as a counter
example take $A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ ($A$ is a $2\times2$ jordan block corresponding to the value $0$
, i.e. $A=J_{2}(0)$ ).

**(c)** : $A$ is unitary and in particular it is normal hence diagonalize

Comment: In fact the only nilpotent $n \times n$ matrix that is diagonalizable is the $0$ matrix.

Comment: Indeed, since it can be proven that the only eigenvalue is $0$ hence the Jordan form is a direct sum of matrices of the form $J_k(0)$ and is diagonizable iff $k=1$ for all the matrices